# How to remove non-straight diagonal lines from text image OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image containing text but with non straight lines drawn on it.

[image]

I want to remove those lines without affecting/removing anything from the text.
For that I used Hough probabilistic transform:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def remove_lines(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1, theta=1*np.pi/180,
                            threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=5)
    # Draw lines on the image
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imwrite('result', img)
```

The result was not as good as I expected:

[image]

The lines were not entirely detected (only some segments, the straight segments, of the lines were detected).
I did some adjustments on `cv2.Canny` and `cv2.HoughLinesP` parameters, but it didn't work too.

I also tried `cv2.createLineSegmentDetector` (Not available in the latest version of opencv due to license issue, so I had to downgrade opencv to version 4.0.0.21):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def remove_lines(filename):
    im = cv2.imread(filename)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Create default parametrization LSD
    lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)

    # Detect lines in the image (Position 0 of the returned tuple are the
    # detected lines)
    lines = lsd.detect(gray)[0]

    # drawn_img = lsd.drawSegments(res, lines)
    for element in lines:
        if (abs(int(element[0][0]) - int(element[0][2])) > 70 or
                abs(int(element[0][1]) - int(element[0][3])) > 70):
            cv2.line(im, (int(element[0][0]), int(element[0][1])), (int(
                element[0][2]), int(element[0][3])), (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imwrite('lsd.jpg', im)
```

The result was  a bit better, but didn't detect the entire lines.

[image]

Any idea how to make the lines detection more efficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove noisy lines from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028493/remove-noisy-lines-from-an-image)

Comment: I just noticed this: I certainly hope those names and phone numbers are invented, and not related to real people! You can get into trouble for posting that! Please replace your images with something that has personal information redacted out if these are real names and phone numbers!

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I took the image from the internet. I just made a random search for text images and I chose this one randomly.. Does this still present a problem?

Comment: No idea. Depends on where you found it and if you have permission to repost it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit my question using another image that does not contain any personal info.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, unfortunately, the answer on the question you mentioned didn't solve my problem.. The final result I got whether affects the text or it does not remove the lines entirely.

Comment: Well, it's impossible to remove the lines without affecting the text at all. I honestly don't think you're going to find a better approach than that. You might get better results by tweaking parameters to match your specific case (the linked question had much larger letters), but IMO that is the best general approach.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to adjust the parameters to get a better result.

Comment: Try increasing the angle threshold and filter on the orientation of the lines and the length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typical methods to remove lines are to use horizontal/vertical kernels or `cv2.HoughLinesP()` but these methods only work if the lines are straight. In this case, the lines are not straight so an idea is to use a diagonal kernel, morphological transformations, and contour filtering to remove the lines from the text. I will be using a previous answer's approach found in [removing horizontal lines in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274961/removing-horizontal-lines-in-image-opencv-python-matplotlib) but with a diagonal kernel

---

We begin by converting the image to grayscale and perform Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image. Next we create a diagonal kernel then perform morph close to detect/filter out the diagonal lines. Since [`cv2.getStructuringElement()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) does not have any built in diagonal kernel, we create our own

[image]

```
# Read in image, grayscale, and Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Create diagonal kernel
kernel = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
```

The image isolated the main diagonal lines but it also included small lines from the text. To remove them we find contours and filter using contour area. If the contour passes our filter, we effectively remove the noise by "filling in" the contour with `cv2.drawContours()`. This leaves us with our desired diagonal lines to remove

[image]

```
# Find contours and filter using contour area to remove noise
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 500:
        cv2.drawContours(opening, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)
```

From here we simply `cv2.bitwise_xor()` with the original image to get our result

[image]

```
# Bitwise-xor with original image
opening = cv2.merge([opening, opening, opening])
result = cv2.bitwise_xor(image, opening)
```

---

**Notes:** It is difficult to remove the lines without affecting the text although it is possible and will need some clever tricks to "repair" the text. Take a look at [remove borders from image but keep text written on borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084229/remove-borders-from-image-but-keep-text-written-on-borders-preprocessing-before/58089157) for a method to reconstruct the missing text. Another method to isolate the diagonal lines would be to take a contrarian approach; instead of trying to detect diagnoal lines, why not try to determine what is not a diagnoal line. You could probably do this by simple filtering techniques. To create dynamic diagonal kernels, you could use [`np.diag()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) for different diagonal line widths

Full code for completeness

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read in image, grayscale, and Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Create diagonal kernel
kernel = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

# Find contours and filter using contour area to remove noise
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 500:
        cv2.drawContours(opening, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Bitwise-xor with original image
opening = cv2.merge([opening, opening, opening])
result = cv2.bitwise_xor(image, opening)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use `connectedComponentsWithStats` to find out the longest two connected component in the image.

Comment: Would you explain more with an example?